# How do I sort a HashMap in descending order by Value and alphabetically by Key?

Tags: java, hashmap

So I have this HashMap

```
HashMap<String, Integer> hm = new HashMap <String, Integer>();
```

And the contents of it:

```
Key: "Apricots" Value: 3
Key: "Kiwi"  Value: 2
Key: "Apple"  Value: 2
Key: "Orange"  Value: 1
```

And I want the output to be where Apple precedes Kiwi alphabetically:

```
Key: "Apricots" Value: 3
Key: "Apple"    Value: 2
Key: "Kiwi"   Value: 2
Key: "Orange"  Value: 1
```

Is it possible to sort this?

Comment: @BasilBourque I mean in the case of a tie between two Values (i.e Value: 2), I would like to store them in lexicographical order. Is this possible?

Comment: So edit your question to say that.

Answer (score 0):

Your question has some ambiguity because the result you have mentioned,  are not alphabetically sorted by key and ordering by value makes no sense.

However, seems like you want to order by only the first letter of the key (so Apple and Appricots become a tie) and if there's a tie, order by the value. Assuming this, I propose the following solution:

```
    Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("Apricots", 3);
    map.put("Kiwi", 2);
    map.put("Apple", 1);
    map.put("Orange", 1);

    List<Map.Entry<String, Integer>> list = map.entrySet().stream()
            .sorted((e1, e2) -> {
                // Compare only the first 2 letters
                int res = e1.getKey().substring(0, 1).compareTo(e2.getKey().substring(0, 1));
                if (res == 0) {
                    // If its a tie, compare values DESC
                    return e2.getValue().compareTo(e1.getValue());
                }

                return res;
            })
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    System.out.println(list);
```

Here we use a custom [comparator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) to order the entries of the map.

Comment: I mean in the case of a tie between two Values (i.e Value: 2), I would like to store them in lexicographical order. I already sorted the Key values beforehand in descending order. What I would like to do is if there is case where I have two of the same Values, I store those 2 values  in lexicographical order

Comment: What do you mean by "already sorted key values beforehand in decending order" and then "where I have two of the same Values, I store those 2 values in lexicographical order"? If you have the list already ordered by the key, if you again try to compare the values for ties, won't that affect the ordering of the keys?